# Magento 2 : Show product ratings for each star, average ratings and % of 5 star ratings on product page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, review, ratings, product-review

I want to display ratings on the product page like this:

[image]

1. **How many users selected 5/4/3/2/1 star ratings**
2. **The average rating, displayed as stars**
3. **Percentage of users selected a 5 star rating**

> I need to add custom code for that, so please don't suggest **getReviewsSummaryHtml**.

Comment: Can you please post you complete solution here? I need to do same but not good in  doing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create and call this new method with product ID. Also make sure you have only 1 rating option enable in admin.

```
public function getAllStart($pid) {
    $review = $this->_objectReview->getCollection()     //\Magento\Review\Model\Review $reviewFactory (_objectReview)
            ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.status_id', 1)
            ->addEntityFilter('product', $pid)          //$pid = > your current product ID
            ->addStoreFilter($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId())
            ->addFieldToSelect('review_id')
    ;
    $review->getSelect()->columns('detail.detail_id')->joinInner(
            ['vote' => $review->getTable('rating_option_vote')], 'main_table.review_id = vote.review_id', array('review_value' => 'vote.value')
    );
    $review->getSelect()->order('review_value DESC');
    $review->getSelect()->columns('count(vote.vote_id) as total_vote')->group('review_value');
    for ($i = 5; $i >= 1; $i--) {
        $arrRatings[$i]['value'] = 0;
    }
    foreach ($review as $_result) {
        $arrRatings[$_result['review_value']]['value'] = $_result['total_vote'];
    }
    return $arrRatings;
    }
```

Comment: yes, I have only single rating active from admin.
so let me try this code

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It's working fine. Many many thanks again

Comment: Where to add this code to above result? I need to do same thing.

Comment: @Jai, You have to put this code in any of your custom module block file and call this method from where you want. Like you can call it from review list page of your theme.

Comment: Can you Please do so I can follow accordingly? You can add how you had done in your work.  Post the code of block you created and how you call in review list page.

Comment: I have used like
$review = $this->_reviewFactory->getCollection()
It's giving me error 
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory::getCollection()

Comment: My error is main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Review\Model\Review) with the same ID "9" already exists. [] []

Comment: How to I get into the template file using object manager?

Comment: Error "Item (Magento\Review\Model\Review) with the same ID "364" already exists."