# How to rate products in product listing page?

Tags: magento2.1.5

How to perform rating in any custom product listing page so that user do not have to go to product detail page to rate it? I got suggestions to look at [Magento 2 : Show product ratings for each star, average ratings and % of 5 star ratings on product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157148/magento-2-show-product-ratings-for-each-star-average-ratings-and-of-5-star) . This code works to get review. But I need a way so that I can post review  and get it recorded in database.

Comment: it's not duplicate, that solutioin is about reading data, I am talking about writing reviews to database from almost anywhere where products are listed.

Answer (score 0):

Call this line in your file where you want to add the reviews html:

```
echo $this->_reviewsHelperBlock->getSummaryHtml($_product, false, false);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate it more?

Comment: You can also go through this link, i think its helpful: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157148/magento-2-show-product-ratings-for-each-star-average-ratings-and-of-5-star